# How to subset a data frame by the last day of each month

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a df :

```
     dates  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10
1999-05-31  66  65  64  63  62  61  60  59  58  57
1999-06-01  67  66  65  64  63  62  61  60  59  58
1999-06-02  68  67  66  65  64  63  62  61  60  59
1999-06-03  69  68  67  66  65  64  63  62  61  60
1999-06-04  70  69  68  67  66  65  64  63  62  61
1999-06-17  79  78  77  76  75  74  73  72  71  70
1999-06-18  80  79  78  77  76  75  74  73  72  71
1999-06-21  81  80  79  78  77  76  75  74  73  72
1999-06-22  82  81  80  79  78  77  76  75  74  73
1999-06-23  83  82  81  80  79  78  77  76  75  74
1999-06-24  84  83  82  81  80  79  78  77  76  75
1999-06-25  85  84  83  82  81  80  79  78  77  76
1999-06-28  86  85  84  83  82  81  80  79  78  77
1999-06-29  87  86  85  84  83  82  81  80  79  78
1999-06-30  88  87  86  85  84  83  82  81  80  79
```

I would like to subset the above df by the last day of each month. Namely, that only the dates 1999-05-31 and 1999-06-30 would be present. The actual data frame is much larger and the last dates might be the 28'th,29'th and so on of each month.
So I would like the output to be something like:

```
dates   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10
1999-05-31  66  65  64  63  62  61  60  59  58  57 
1999-06-30  88  87  86  85  84  83  82  81  80  79
1999-10-29  175 174 173 172 171 170 169 168 167 166
```

I was trying to find some function in zoo or other packages but could not find one... Greatful for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This selects the last days of the month:

```
df[as.numeric(substr(as.Date(df$dates) + 1, 9, 10))
   < as.numeric(substr(df$dates, 9, 10)), ]

#        dates V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1  1999-05-31 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58  57
#15 1999-06-30 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80  79
```

Note that this solution depends on the absolute number of months per day (irrespective of your data).

If you want to select the last day of each month in your actual data, use this command:

```
df[c(diff(as.numeric(substr(df$dates, 9, 10))) < 0, TRUE), ]
```

Comment: Thank you once again Sven! You have great R skills!

Comment: Ok! Thanks!:) But why is `TRUE` included? I seem to get the same answer if I exclude it...

Comment: The command `diff(as.numeric(substr(df$dates, 9, 10))) < 0` returns a logical vector of length `nrow(df)-1`, hence I combined this vector with an additional `TRUE` to use it for the selection of a subset of rows of `df`. The length of a vector and the length of a logical index vector should be identical. If the logical index is shorter by one element, the first value of the logical vector is used as its last value too.

Comment: If i want to find the first day of each month instead of last day of each month, do I think correctly that I could change df[c(diff(as.numeric(substr(df$dates, 9, 10))) < 0, TRUE), ] to df[c(diff((as.numeric(substr(df$dates, 9, 10))))+1 > 0, TRUE), ] ? :)

Comment: @user1665355 No, just change the position of `TRUE`: `df[c(TRUE, diff(as.numeric(substr(df$dates, 9, 10))) < 0), ]`

Comment: Thanks again:) I think that your solutions is always the most "nice" in terms of awesome looking code:)

Comment: Why is it actually picking first day of each month is the order of TRUE and diff(...) is reversed? :)

Comment: @user1665355 Because the positions of the selected elements increase by one position (relative to the selection of last days). Since the last days are inherently followed by the first days, this command now selects the first days in your dataset.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming dates are formatted properly as dates, and the source data frame is `x`.

```
> library(xts)
> x[endpoints(x$dates, on = "months"), ]
        dates V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  1999-05-31 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58  57
15 1999-06-30 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80  79
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I then find the first observation in each month? Could I simply do x[endpoints(x$dates, on = "months")+1, ] or is there some specific function for that? Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% 
  mutate(yr_mnth = format(dates, '%Y-%m')) %>% 
  group_by(yr_mnth) %>% 
  filter(dates == max(dates))

# or if you wanted the first observation of each month:
df %>% 
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% 
  mutate(yr_mnth = format(dates, '%Y-%m')) %>% 
  group_by(yr_mnth) %>% 
  filter(dates == min(dates))
```